How to select faces along curve/path/edge?
Is there a way to select mesh polygons along a curve/path/edge?
A mesh is an exported profile of an area of the earth's surface (approximately 1 km by 1 km in size). There is a road running through this section in real life. A path/curve/edge is a road, which is easy to make directly in blender, since the mesh of an area of ​​the earth's surface is exported with the texture of its topographic plan.
I would like to leave only those polygons in the plot mesh that go along the path/curve/edge in order to export it to DXF to continue working on it in another program.
Since there will be more than a dozen such meshes-areas, that’s why I would like to automate this process.
I would be grateful for any possible solutions/ideas, including those not related to Blender.



There's probably some facier way to do this with python or geometry nodes but, if you turn the curve into a mesh and merge it with the plane, you can use proportional editing set to Constant to move it up by X amount and everything at the set distance would go up. Selecting that displaced geometry afterwards with box select should be easy. Then just delete the rest and the curve and move it down again

A very interesting and quite suitable solution. I immediately thought about Python, just until I figure out what algorithm should be applied here. It is quite possible that Blender's internal API already has the required algorithm. In the meantime, I'll use your wonderful solution. Thank you very much.
